# John worked at the factory and <so had his grandfather> <his grandfather had too>

Tags: sentence-meaning

I know (1a) = (1b) = (1c):
**(1a)** *John worked at the factory, as **did** his grandfather*.
**(1b)** *John worked at the factory and so **did** his grandfather*.
**(1c)** *John worked at the factory and his grandfather **did** too*.

---

Can I say the same about the next sentences, that (2a) = (2b) = (2c)?:
**(2a)** *John worked at the factory, as **had** his grandfather*.
**(2b)** *John worked at the factory and so **had** his grandfather*.
**(2c)** *John worked at the factory and his grandfather **had** too*.

Comment: c sounds odd to me in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they mean the same thing, but 2c is somewhat awkward. I doubt many native speakers would choose it over 2b.

In 1c, “too” is apt because what is being said is completely parallel: both worked at the same factory at the same time.

In 2c, “too” is not apt because the situations are not exactly the same, the factory is the same but the time is not. A more natural way to alter 2b is

> John worked at the factory where his grandfather had once worked.

Note that I am not saying 2c is ungrammatical. Nor am I saying it would not be understood. “Too” just does not sound completely natural to me with the change in tense.

Answer (score 1):

These all sound grammatical. Some might sound more natural than others depending on the context.

"Had" is more precise than "did" to convey that when John was working at the factory, his grandfather was no longer working there.